# how to send an sms after a user registers on a website using php

Tags: php, forms, api, sms

Hello I have a registration form, that carries fields such as name, phone number and email. These details are sent to a database, I am trying to implement a system whereby after registration, an SMS is sent to the user who filled the form as a form of confirmation, instead of emails, I know I need a provider to do this, but from the region where I come from i haven't seen a reliable company that can do this, so I am asking for the best suggestions, I am building with PHP programming language.

Comment: May be https://www.twilio.com/

Comment: "i know i need a provider to do this" — Yes. "i havent seen a reliable company that can do this, so i am asking for the best suggestions" — Service provider recommendation questions are off-topic as they tend to attract spam.

Answer (score 0):

We do a similar thing. We personally use [TextMagic](https://www.textmagic.com/) but most proviers are the similar. You are generally given a few options, the most common being an email proxy or a web page call. For instance, to send messages we use:

```
mail('07123456789@textmagic.com', 'SECRET_CODE', 'Our message');
```

Here, there mobile number before the `@textmagic.com` is the number we're sending to, the `SECRET_CODE` is our pass key and `Our message` whatever we want to send.

The web version would be similar, something like:

```
https://www.textmagic.com/app/api?username=xxxx&password=yyyy& cmd=send&text=Our%20message&phone=447123456789
```

Really what you want to do is find a service like this then check the [API documentation](http://api.textmagic.com/). It's a very simple thing to do, but your question is a little too general to give anything more specific.

Comment: i checked out textmagic and i tried to register, but i got a message that they were upgrading  to have a better system